# Finding the boundaries on $\rho$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates

For spherical coordinates, how would we find the boundary on $\rho$ for the volume enclosed by the surfaces $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $x^2 + y^2 + (z-a)^2 = a^2$? I'm not sure how to algebraic show this, as I can't really do it visually either. Visually, I know it should depend on the value of $\phi$, but that's about it.

I was able to find the boundary on $\rho$ visually, when it was constant bounds as in this question I had submitted earlier: [Spherical coordinates and finding the boundaries for $\rho$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257530/spherical-coordinates-and-finding-the-boundaries-for-rho/2257579?noredirect=1#comment4645027_2257579)

Comment: hint:  convert the equations you've given from rectangular coordinates to spherical coordinates and try to simplify.

Comment: I got $\rho = 2a \cos \phi$. Is this correct, and is that the usual method to algebraically find boundaries of $\rho$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the answer posted, and believe the correct answer is indeed $2a\cos\phi$. Here is why. Let us view this region in the $x$-$z$ plane, and since it is symmetric about the $z$ axis, this is all we need to look at. Taking some line in some direction specified by $(\theta,\phi)$, how far does $\rho$ go? Below I have plotted what this looks like with $a=2$:
[image]

$\rho$ goes as far as the surface $x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2=a^2$, so we solve for this.
$$\rho^2\sin^2\phi\cos^2\theta+\rho^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta+(\rho\cos\phi-a)^2=a^2$$
$$\implies\rho^2\sin^2\phi+\rho^2\cos^2\phi-2a\rho\cos\phi=0$$
$$\implies\rho=2a\cos\phi$$

---

Also, we can check that this is correct. Take the angle $\pm\pi/4$. This is along one of the red lines in my plot. These lines go from $(0,0)$ to $(\pm a,a)$, and so have length $\sqrt{(\pm a)^2+a^2}=\sqrt2a$. Meanwhile using our formula, $2a\cos(\pi/4)=2a\times\frac1{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2a$ as well.

We can also check what happens when we take the angle $\phi=0$. In the image, this of course goes from $(0,0)$ to $(0,2a)$, which has length $2a$. This agrees with $2a\cos(0)=2a$. So our answer seems to be right.

Comment: In spherical coordinates, the cone is drawn by holding the angle $\phi$ constant at $\frac{\pi}{4}$. $\phi$ is not 0 at any point. If $\phi=0$, then the function is a straight vertical line. $\phi$ is a value for the angle between the z axis and $\rho$.  See Paul's Online Math notes for reference:  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx

Comment: @JHStrom Yes, I agree that $\phi=\pi/4$ on the cone. However OP wants to compute a volume integral for the region bounded by this cone **_and the sphere_**, and so to reach regions other than _just_ the cone's surface, $\phi$ must change, and it varies from $-\pi/4$ to $\pi/4$. With your method, how can you reach the point $(0,a)$ for instance? It is certainly in the region, but has $\phi=0$.

Comment: Apologies, yes you are correct.  I suppose I forgot the OP's question.

Comment: @JHStrom If you correct/improve your answer, I will un-downvote it (right now I am supposedly locked until it is edited). I'd appreciate if you did the same :)

Comment: Fixed.  Apologies about the downvote though, seems i'm locked in.  No hard feelings, sorry for being wrong :(

Comment: @JHStrom No worries, just hope OP realises the mistake soon haha. I have edited my question so you're free to change your vote if you wish.

Comment: Cheers!  
I think I'm understanding it a bit more now. Basically we look at where $\rho$ "changes" in length in the region (which is why integrating it with a constant boundary ($\sqrt{2}a$) in this case is incorrect) and so we must substitute the respective coordinates for $x,y,z$ into an equation that allows any possible point $\textbf{x}$ to attain a value in this region (which should show how far $\rho$ ranges)?  
Might've bumbled a bit so hope you understand my question

Comment: @PaulWoch Yes, it seems like you've got it :)

Comment: Would you say it's also useful to substitute one of the ordinates to be zero (so like $x=0,y=0$ or $z=0$) to see the cross-section on a 2-d plane (since we can inspect and observe any symmetry in the equation)?  
Also, is it usual to find sketching these 3-d surfaces to be difficult? I almost always use a graph sketcher, but in an exam i won't have that...

Comment: @PaulWoch Yes, it is useful. In fact you could use such a method to construct a plot - substitute $z=constant$ and the cone gives circles in the $z=constant$ planes, and the radius is different based on which $z$ you chose. Similarly, $x=0$ gives circles on the sphere which are $y^2+(z-a)^2=a^2, but gives $z=|y|$ on the cone, and this can also help draw the graph. (1/2)

Comment: Often in questions you will have a bit of symmetry, such as in this example where in $z=const$, you get a circle no matter what. There is no need to sketch this, you can characterise a circle just by its radius/diameter. So this is sketched in the $x$-$z$ or $y$-$z$ planes to give the above diagram. If you need to draw 3D, try and plot in these three planes by substituting $0$, and then see if you can figure out what happens in between. (2)

Answer (score -1):

This surface is just a cone bounded from 0, at the origin, to $2a$, in the positive z direction.  In spherical coordinates, the equation of an right circular cone is $\phi = \frac{\pi}{ 4}$.  The minimum value for $\rho$ can be calculated by dropping a perpendicular line from the intersection point of the cone and the sphere.  For this right triangle, $\rho^2 = a^2 + a^2$, so $\rho = \sqrt{2}a$ here.

For the volume integral, the angle $\phi$ will go from $- \frac{\pi}{ 4} $ to $\frac{\pi}{ 4}$, and in doing so will hit $\phi = 0$.  At this point, $\rho$ is simply a vertical line up the $z$ axis through the sphere.  So, it is evident that at this point $\rho$ is at its maximum value:  $2a$.

Comment: Hmm, my sources say that $\rho$ ranges from $0$ to $2a \cos \phi$.  This is found by substituting each respective spherical substitution for $x,y,z$. Also, the maximum can't be constant right? Since visually, the length of the vector from the origin to the "top" of the surface changes.

Comment: Both of our answers are exactly the same.  As I've said, $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$.  Plug in this value and evaluate.  $\rho = \sqrt{2a}$ at maximum.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm confused because for some reason I think that $\phi$ shouldn't be constant? I mean I know it is in this case, but when we're integrating with respect to $\phi$, some answers would be much more different depending on if we substituted $\phi$ in or just let $\phi$ be our variable?

Comment: $\phi$ is constant for a right circular cone in spherical coordinates.  Paul's Online Math notes (see the bottom of the page):  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx

Comment: @JHStrom You said this is just a cone bounded by $z=a$, but it is not, due to the sphere.